# How to understand the stream map function parameter?

Tags: java, steam

I had a little confused about the Stream map method.
There is the simple source code can run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("hello", "world", "I", "love", "you");
        words.stream().map(String::length).forEach(System.out::println);

    }
```

The map() signature:   Stream map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
The String::length function signature: public int length(), it do not match Function<? super T, ? extends R>.

In my option, I think the function which give to words.stream().map should have 1 parameter, but string::length do not have any input parameter just return int.

It looks like every element "word" in words stream invoke String.length(), but i do not understand how to do? why the string::length signature do not need match the Function signature (R apply(T t))?

Great appreciate!

Comment: For non-static methods, the object on which the method is called is considered the first input argument of a lambda or method reference.  In this case, `String.length` is a non-static method, so each String value in the Stream is the first (and only) input argument to the Function.

Comment: Take a look at the oracle's tutorial on generics https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: Thanks guys, i get the answer! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The job of [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) is to apply some code to each element in the stream’s content, and collect the output of that code for use as an element in a new stream.

The `map` method applies the lambda or [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) passed against each element in the stream. You passed a method reference `String :: length` to your `map` method call. So the first stream asks each of its “word” strings for its length. Each length number becomes an element in a new stream of numbers.

Your call to `forEach` acts on the elements of the new second stream of numbers.

You said:

> It looks like every element "word" in words stream invoke `String.length()`, but i do not understand how to do?

That is the job being done by the `Stream#map` method: Apply the `String#length` method against each of the stream’s elements. The results, each length, is fed to a new stream of numbers, in your code.

You said:

> I think the function which give to words.stream().map should have 1 parameter, but string::length do not have any input parameter just return int.

`length` is a method on the `String` class. So every `String` object carries that method.

You have a stream of `String` objects. The `Stream#map` method applies your method reference to each of its elements. So `map` is calling `length` on each of your stream’s `String` objects (each of your “words”).